# PyQ5- Adding action to save cancel and apply buttons

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to make a simple information table with saving users' inputs. I created the information table with the save, cancel, and apply button. But I can't add action to the buttons.

Save button: should save the new user information to the bottom line of the previous users' information.

Cancel button: interrupt the program.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class InputDialog(QDialog):
    """Dialog."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Information Window')
        dlglayout = QVBoxLayout()
        formlayout = QFormLayout()
        formlayout.addRow('Fırst Name:', QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow('Second Name:', QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow('Age:', QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow('Marital Status:', QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow('Education:', QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow('Job:', QLineEdit())
        dlglayout.addLayout(formlayout)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox()
        btns.setStandardButtons(
            QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        dlglayout.addWidget(btns)
        self.setLayout(dlglayout)
    def getInputs(self):
        return self.first.text(), self.second.text()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = InputDialog()
    if dialog.exec():
        print(dialog.getInputs())
    exit(0)
```

Comment: i stucked at buttons functions (save and cancel), nothing happens when you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If the QDialogButtonBox is to be used then the button actions are issued through the accepted and rejected signals, so these signals must be connected to the "accept" and "reject" slot of the QDialog, respectively.

On the other hand "first" and "second" have never been created so they would also throw an exception.

```
class InputDialog(QDialog):
    """Dialog."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Initializer."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Information Window")

        self.first = QLineEdit()
        self.second = QLineEdit()

        dlglayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        formlayout = QFormLayout()
        formlayout.addRow("Fırst Name:", self.first)
        formlayout.addRow("Second Name:", self.second)
        formlayout.addRow("Age:", QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow("Marital Status:", QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow("Education:", QLineEdit())
        formlayout.addRow("Job:", QLineEdit())
        dlglayout.addLayout(formlayout)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox()
        btns.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        dlglayout.addWidget(btns)

        btns.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        btns.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getInputs(self):
        return self.first.text(), self.second.text()
```

Comment: thank you but again I didn't quite understand what should I do. how can I connect these to the accept and reject slots? Can you please show me the completed code for this program?

Comment: @OsmanIsiktas My code shows that example in detail, have you analyzed the difference between my code and yours?

Comment: yes but that didn't work, connect functions should be solved i guess.But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @OsmanIsiktas What do you mean by "connect functions should be solved i guess"? If you mean that your IDE does not recognize "connect" then the problem has nothing to do with PyQt5 but rather that the IDE you are using is unable to recognize the signature of the pyqt5 library.

Comment: When I run your code, and enter the information to the box and save, it prints them. But I want to store all users informations in one table or maybe in the excel file. I don't know how to do that

Comment: @OsmanIsiktas That is not pointed out by your question and neither is it pointed out in your comment: *i stucked at buttons functions (save and cancel), nothing happens when you clicked.*. So do not ask me for more than what you indicated in your post, Bye.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english , again thanks for your effort